# How to filter product collection in Multi-Source Inventory?

Tags: magento2.4

Please elaborate what is a standard way to filter Product Collection
in Multi-Source Inventory in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

you no need to use Product collection for the purposes you mentioned.
You can apply filtering on the level of SourceItemRepository (`\Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceItemRepositoryInterface::getList`)
https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/InventoryApi/Api/SourceItemRepositoryInterface.php#L43

In the search criteria which is passed as a parameter to the getList method you can specify filtering by SKU and/or Source Code.